# Measuring distance every 10 degrees

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, measurements

I have a point in the sea laguna and want to measure distance from the point to the closest shoreline within specified interval: every 10 degrees - new measurement.

How can I do it automatically (cause I have quite a lot points)?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 with Advanced license.

Comment: what if the shoreline and the x*10 degrees circles have multiple intersections?

Comment: Or none at all?

Comment: if you can draw a line to your "closest shoreline", I can show you some arcpy code that will plot a point for every specified distance along that line. If the data is unprojected, I suspect degrees would be your units though I'm used to running this script using units of feet or meters.

Comment: mm, I think to draw the line to the closest shoreline it is not a problem at all. But still for every point it will be different shoreline. Basically, I thought to create kind of "star" template and then to do intersection. But I am in doubt maybe you have a better suggestions. If it is possible, I would like to try your code. About shoreline and x*10 degrees circles: I haven't understood idea clearly, where should be center of every circle? Thank you!